# How fast must a torus spin to have a felt gravity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, centrifugal-force, centripetal-force

Given a rotating *torus* (like a gyroscope or a rotary) with a radius of *1km*, how fast must it rotate to have someone inside the torus feel normal gravity of *1G*?

Comment: Now that I read the question myself, it looks like am asking a homework question. But no, I am just curious on how fast would DS9 have to spin to make one feel like normal gravity, without the means of creating artificial gravity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the radius of the torus is $r$ and the tangential velocity is $v$ then the acceleration towards the centre is:

$$ a = \frac{v^2}{r} \tag{1} $$

So just set $a = 9.81$ m/sec$^2$ and you have your answer.

If you prefer to have the answer in terms of the rotation rate then use the equation $v = r\omega$ to rewrite equation (1) as:

$$ a = \omega^2r $$

where $\omega$ is the [angular velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity). If your torus takes $T$ seconds to rotate once then $\omega = 2\pi/T$.

Comment: Great. So about 100m/s ie. 360kmh. Hrm, sounds doable ;-) That is a lot slower then the ISS is traveling around the earth anyway (7.7 km/s?), isn't it?

Comment: @towi Indeed. The hard part of that project would be to get a torus with a 100 km radius into low earth orbit in the first place. It also begs the question what benefit it would have. The point of a space laboratory is to *avoid*  gravity influencing the experiments.

Comment: @Philipp - put the experiments on the hub (which rotates opposite to the "wheel" so it experiences zero acceleration) and the living quarters on the outside. People will be able to eat normal food and take showers, yet science is served.